# jssc windows and linux

Tags: linux, windows, jssc

I'm using jssc to communicate with equipment.
In Windows and Linux the program was ok but I had a problem with virus and i format my pc then the program don't work with Windows but with Linux the program works fine.
I don't know why the program stopped working.
The program code is:

```
    try {
        command = new String(commandSend);
        serialPort.writeBytes(command.getBytes());
        logger.info("Sending to port " + a.getPort() + " " + command);
        Thread.sleep(1000);//Wait 0.8 seconds

        retorno = serialPort.readString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Problems with send/receive command with the analyzer");
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
        logger.error(e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you could search where the code stops and then edit your question

Comment: Sure, the problem is in Linux serialPort.readString() return normally but in Windows returns null, it's very confusing the program works fine until I format my pc then teh program don't work

Answer (score 0):

After formatting your PC, please install driver for your UART IC.